# OS X app freeze when closing window during CALayer animation when Tweetbot is running

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I made a custom `NSControl` to use it as a custom layer backed button.

When the `MyButton` instance receives `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` events it changes its `backgroundLayer`'s `backgroundColor`and its `textLayer`'s `foregroundColor`.

It's using layers so the changes are implicitly animated.

But on `mouseUp` if the mouse is inside the `MyButton`'s instance frame I call the linked action through `sendAction(_:to:)` method.

I linked the action to a method closing the current window and opening another one but sometimes the app freeze after the second window shows up.

I tried several things and it seems related to the layer animations, maybe something to do before closing the window that I'm not aware of.

**UPDATE: It's Tweetbot ! If Tweetbot is running it's freezing the app! As soon as I quit it the app becomes responsive again.**

You can find an example project here :
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/378166/CALayerFreeze.zip

*(note that you'll sometimes have to try several times before the bug occurs)*

Here's the code for `MyButton`.

```
class MyButton: NSControl {
    let title = "Click me!"

    // Init
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    deinit {
        trackingAreas.forEach { self.removeTrackingArea($0) }
    }

    // Layer + Tracking Area configuration
    var backgroundLayer = CALayer()
    var textLayer = CATextLayer()

    func setup() {
        wantsLayer = true

        backgroundLayer.frame = NSRect(origin: .zero, size: frame.size)
        backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        layer?.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)

        textLayer.frame = NSRect(origin: .zero, size: frame.size)
        textLayer.string = title
        textLayer.foregroundColor = NSColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.64).CGColor
        layer?.addSublayer(textLayer)

        addTrackingArea(
            NSTrackingArea(
                rect: bounds,
                options: [.MouseEnteredAndExited, .EnabledDuringMouseDrag, .ActiveInKeyWindow],
                owner: self,
                userInfo: nil
            )
        )
    }

    // States
    private func normal() {
        // ——— COMMENTING THIS MAKES THE BEACHBALL GO AWAY
        backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        textLayer.foregroundColor = NSColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.64).CGColor
    }

    private func highlight() {
        // ——— COMMENTING THIS MAKES THE BEACHBALL GO AWAY
        backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.grayColor().CGColor
        textLayer.foregroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.64).CGColor
    }

    // Tracking events
    var isMouseDown = false

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(theEvent)
        isMouseDown = true
        highlight()
    }

    override func mouseUp(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseUp(theEvent)
        isMouseDown = false
        normal()

        if frame.contains(convertPoint(theEvent.locationInWindow, toView: self)) {
            sendAction(action, to: target)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you say " COMMENTING THIS MAKES THE BEACHBALL GO AWAY" does it apply to both lines or only one of them?

Comment: It's both lines IIRC

Comment: Both lines create animations inside the view (because layer implicitly animates the changes) so yes it's both.

Comment: Ok. I've downloaded your project and ran it a dozen times but no beachball or freeze in sight. Not sure why you get this issue.

Comment: I tested on both my iMac at work and my iMac at home and I get the same issue. Maybe it's related to some config I have on both… (I sync via mackup)

Comment: You say "but **sometimes** the app freeze" so indeed my guess is that the issue comes from something unrelated to your code. Does Console.app show anything when this issue happens?

Comment: Ok I tried just now and can't get to reproduce the problem ಠ_ಠ… Console didn't show a thing, and I even tried to debug the app while it was frozen and everything looked fine. Just it was frozen… It's crazy…

Comment: UPDATE: It's TweetBot ! If TweetBot is running it's freezing the app! As soon as I quit it the app becomes responsive again.